# wxWidgets pprogrammaticaly move to next input control

Tags: c++11, wxwidgets, keyevent

I originally had code that set the focus to the first widget in a dialog, in the onInit method. But there were problems with it: if I pressed TAB, indeed focus moved to next control (wxTextCtrl), which got the blue 'focus' color, but **the 'focus' color/highlight was not removed from previous focus widget**. So now it looked like both first and second control had focus at the same time...

When cycling manually (by pressing TAB) full circle (till last control and then wrap around to the first), suddenly all worked well. That is, when moving focus from first control to next one, the first visually lost focus (blue color was removed) as it should. From now on, only one item had the focus color/highlight.

So instead of setting focus on the first control, I tried a different approach: I set the focus to the last control in the dialog, which is always the OK button. Next, I want to emulate programmatically that a TAB is pressed and received by the dialog. So I wrote this (inside Dialog::onInit):

```
    m_buttonOK->SetFocus();
    wxKeyEvent key;
    key.SetEventObject(this);
    key.SetEventType(wxEVT_CHAR);
    key.m_keyCode=WXK_TAB;
    ProcessWindowEvent(key);
```

Now the focus indeed moves away from the OK button, but it does not wrap around to the first control.
Only when I manually press TAB after the dialog opened, the first item gets focus.

Question: why does this wrapping around to set focus on first widget not work with the code shown above?

Comment: do you have wxPanel as a parent for all your controls or handle TABbing yourself?

Comment: somewhere somehow you definitly have focus event handler and it is not being skipped. Moreover - if you were using wxPanel to hold all you controls, instead of wxFrame, nothing like this will ever happened. Please use following structure: `wxFrame/wxDialog -> wxPanel -> wxTextCtrl/wxButton/etc`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your initial problem is almost certainly related to not calling `event.Skip()` in one of your event handlers, see the note in [wxFocusEvent documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_focus_event.html).

Second, you can't send wx events to the native windows, they don't know anything about it. In this particular case you can use [wxWindow::Navigate()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_window.html#a86904f6785df4af6036b33383490a805) to do what you want, but generally speaking what you're doing simple can't, and won't, work reliably.

Comment: I only have event handlers for the three buttons: Cancel, OK and Restore. So I don't think forgetting event.Skip() is the issue here, Thanks for the tip for wxWindow::Navigate(), I will look up documentation and try it.

Comment: All I can say is that the only way to get more than one control appear as if it had the focus is by handling, ant not skipping, `wxFocusEvent`. If you find a different way to do it, please try to reproduce it with the smallest amount of code and open a bug for it because it would be a bug.

Comment: Hi, I'm not handling a wxFocusEvent. I don't have time to make such an example for the foreseeable future... I need to focus on the job at hand. Perhaps later. But although I like wxWidgets and Qt a lot, probably I will use Uno in the future. https://platform.uno/